# Use Asynchronous Activity vs have workflow wait for signal

Tags: cadence-workflow, temporal-workflow

Let's say we need to send user an email and wait for user to reply and then continue the workflow. Should we create an async activity to send the email, and when the reply email comes, we complete the activity? Or should we create a normal activity to send the email, and then the workflow await a signal, and when the reply email comes, we send the signal to the workflow? Are these 2 options equivalent? Or there are some difference can be used to decide which one to use for different activities?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I recommend the *activity then signal* approach for this use case. The reason is that sending an email and waiting for a reply are two different tasks with different timeouts and retry policies.

If *send email* activity fails it is expected to be retried on a short timeout on a pretty tight retry schedule. At the same time the timeout for the user action is expected to be much larger (potentially days or weeks) and is usually not retriable.

*Edit to answer the retry question:*

> But what if we do want to retry? Say we expect the user to reply the
>   email within a day, otherwise we send it again. We can retry the
>   entire workflow but that is not ideal since send email and user reply
>   is only part of the workflow. Should we make it a child workflow and
>   have retry on the child workflow?

You retry the whole interaction. See the fileprocessing example of retrying part of a workflow. Here are [Go SDK](https://github.com/temporalio/temporal-go-samples/blob/df15cf9307edb9f97c9f8772aef2b79bd803ff3f/fileprocessing/workflow.go#L27) and [Java SDK](https://github.com/temporalio/temporal-java-samples/blob/143902cba3e14aa11f3b90784baf53406c329fd2/src/main/java/io/temporal/samples/fileprocessing/FileProcessingWorkflowImpl.java#L57) versions of it.

Comment: But what if we do want to retry? Say we expect the user to reply the email within a day, otherwise we send it again. We can retry the entire workflow but that is not ideal since send email and user reply is only part of the workflow. Should we make it a child workflow and have retry on the child workflow?

Comment: Thank you for pointers on retry part of a workflow! I'm new to Cadence, still learning. But I'm still not sure when is appropriate to use async activity. The only example is from the document saying "For example it is forwarded to an external system through a message queue. And the reply comes through a different queue." But based on your answer, couldn't we say send to an external system message queue and wait for reply on a different queue are two different tasks with different timeout and retry policies? If it's because the reply is expected to be very fast, any guideline on how fast?

Comment: It depends on your business logic. If you are OK with waiting for the activity timeout to retry if putting message in a queue failed then you can model it as a async activity. Usually it works OK for short activities, but doesn't work for long ones.

Comment: Sorry, is the pointer you gave is retrying the whole workflow? "// Retry the whole sequence from the first activity on any error" . Did you paste a wrong link?

Comment: Look at the samples. They retry a function that workflow calls not the whole worklfow.